# Python thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to use thread pool to speed up the process. Though there is no error in compilation, 'entering calc' is not displayed. Is my code correct?

Moreover, how to clear the screen of the Shell. I tried the methods searched from the webs but they don't work.

Furthermore, I found the followings. Why?

print x, args, kwargs // error

print(x, args, kwargs) // correct

Thank you very much.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import time

def rand():
    return np.random.normal(0, 1, 1)

class myClass:
    def __init__( self, a = 6, b = 6.5):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.pool = Pool(processes=4)

    def calc(self, i, j):
        print('entering calc')
        return self.a**i + self.b**j

    def compute(self, n):
        result = [self.pool.apply_async(self.calc, (rand(), rand())) for k in range(n)]
        return result

 A = myClass()
 r = A.compute(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is most probably because in later versions of python (i.e Python 3.x) print statements require parentheses